# How do I read formatted data with comments in Fortran?

Tags: format, fortran

I've got some time-domain data in a file I need to read with Fortran that looks like repetitions of this:

```
0.0000E+000
       2  %  number of particles
       4  %  number of values
0.00000E+000
0.00000E+000
0.00000E+000
0.00000E+000
       4  %  number of values 
0.00000E+000
0.00000E+000
0.00000E+000
0.00000E+000
```

where the first line is the current time and I need the other values in an array sized by the number of particles & values. Ideally, each call to a `read_values()` subroutine would grab one chunk of this data (at the next time), but I'm not sure how to skip the comments. Is there an easy way to simply advance to the next line after a read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortran I/O is normally record based (the new `stream` access method is not).  For formatted files this mean lines.   A Fortran `read` normally reads from a line and the next read will read the next line ... unless you explicitly use the non-advancing option.   If you know which lines have integers, read the integers with a format that uses just that part of the line.  That appears to be `I8` with your file.  The read won't process the rest of the line with the comment.  The next read will read from the next line.   If you don't know which lines contain which type of data, then you can read each line into a string and analyze the string to decide how to read from the string.